# How to I cast items from a "With" query in Simple.Data?

Tags: c#, casting, simple.data

Using the example from the documentation:

```
public class Artist
{
  public int ArtistId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

...

var eagerDynamicArtist = db.Artists.FindAllByArtistId(22).WithAlbums().FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Artist {0} {1}", eagerDynamicArtist.ArtistId, eagerDynamicArtist.Name);

foreach (var album in eagerDynamicArtist.Albums)
{
  Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", album.Title);
}
```

Problem is, the Albums list is returned null (the generated query is OK).
It works if I change `Albums` to:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Albums { get; set; }
```

How can I explicitly cast the `Albums` table, while defining the `Albums` list as `IEnumerable<Album>`?

Note: I'm using other tables obviously, but with a similar structure. I'm assuming the "Album" table doesn't magically cast because the POCO class has some more fields (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Albums property should be an IList<Album> rather than IEnumerable<Album>.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you should probably note this in the [documentation](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/LazyVsEagerLoading.htm)... Or did I miss something?

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything, and in fact the example given there is misleading. I'll get that fixed, thanks for pointing it out.